# Calculating modulus for large numbers in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, modulus

I'm trying to calculate big modulus in PL/SQL. I implemented a method that I found on this location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number under Modulo operation on IBAN. But I get wrong results when I use this number: 221021290110000123452229211210282900128222984.

This is how the method needs to be done:

*Piece-wise calculation D mod 97 can be done in many ways. One such way is as follows:*

1. Starting from the leftmost digit of D, construct a number using the first 9 digits and call it N.
2. Calculate N mod 97. If the result is less than 10, prefix the result with a 0, giving a result in the range 00 to 96.
3. Construct a new 9-digit N by concatenating above result (step 2) with the next 7 digits of D. If there are fewer than 7 digits remaining in D but at least one, then construct a new N, which will have less than 9 digits, from the above result (step 2) followed by the remaining digits of D
4. Repeat steps 2–3 until all the digits of D have been processed

The result of the final calculation in step 2 will be D mod 97 = N mod 97.

I did some logging, these are the results of all the modulo steps:

```
221021290110000123452229211210282900128222984 (221021290 % 97 = 0)
00110000123452229211210282900128000000 (001100001 % 97 = 21)
2123452229211210282900128000000 (212345222 & 97 = 0)
009211210282900128000000 (009211210 % 97 = 90)
90282900128000000 (902829001 % 97 = 46)
4628000000 (462800000 % 97 = 2)
020 = 20
```

The result needs to be 1. I checked it with a modulo calculator and it needs to be 1. With most numbers the calcutor is correct.

This is the code I made, how is it possible that this number isn't correct:

```
create or replace function doubleDiget (iban number)
return varchar2
as
begin
  if(iban <= 9) then
    return concat('0',iban);
  else
    return iban;
  end if;
end doubleDiget;

create or replace FUNCTION modbig (iban number)   
    RETURN varchar2                     
      AS  
      lengthIban number(38);
      modUitkomts number(38);
      modUitkomtsc varchar(38);
      restIban varchar(38);
      modlength number(38);
  BEGIN

  modUitkomts := SUBSTR(iban,0,9) mod 97;
  modUitkomtsc := doubleDiget(modUitkomts);
  restIban := concat(modUitkomtsc,SUBSTR(iban,10)); 
  dbms_output.put_line(restIban);

  loop
    if( length(restIban) >= 9) then
        modUitkomts := SUBSTR(restIban,0,9) mod 97;
        modUitkomtsc := doubleDiget(modUitkomts);
        restIban := concat(modUitkomtsc,SUBSTR(restIban,10)); 
        dbms_output.put_line(restIban);
    else
      exit;
    end if;
  end loop;

  modUitkomts := restIban mod 97;
  return modUitkomts;


END modbig;

begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(modbig(221021290110000123452229211210282900128222984));  
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `VARCHAR2` instead of `NUMBER`:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     FUNCTION modbig(iban VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS -- won't be rounded
  3        lengthIban   NUMBER(38);
  4        modUitkomts  NUMBER(38);
  5        modUitkomtsc VARCHAR(38);
  6        restIban     VARCHAR(50);
  7        modlength    NUMBER(38);
  8     BEGIN
  9        restIban     := iban;
 10        modUitkomts  := SUBSTR(restIban, 0, 9) MOD 97;
 11        modUitkomtsc := LPAD(modUitkomts, 2, '0');
 12        restIban := concat(modUitkomtsc, SUBSTR(iban, 10));
 13  
 14        LOOP
 15           IF (length(restIban) >= 9) THEN
 16              modUitkomts  := SUBSTR(restIban, 0, 9) MOD 97;
 17              modUitkomtsc := LPAD(modUitkomts, 2, '0');
 18              restIban := concat(modUitkomtsc, SUBSTR(restIban, 10));
 19           ELSE
 20              EXIT;
 21           END IF;
 22        END LOOP;
 23        modUitkomts := restIban MOD 97;
 24        RETURN modUitkomts;
 25     END modbig;
 26  
 27  BEGIN
 28     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
 29        modbig('221021290110000123452229211210282900128222984')); -- varchar2
 30  END;
 31  /
1
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Explanation: the `NUMBER` dataype has a precision of about 38 digits, so this **will be rounded** for very large number, hence your output ending in `0000` instead of the digits you did input.